# React - pass child value as props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React, sorry if this is too basic.

I have an app which has an api token which needs to be passed down as `props` to many components, but which is not fetched at Parent component App.jsx.

My token is fetched at child component  Spotify.jsx, and so I've tried to implement this like so:

1. set my token with `this.state.spotifyToken = ''` at Parent component
2. create a callback function `onConnectWithSpotify()`, also at Parent
3. pass this callback function to Child component as `props`
4. call function and update `this.state.spotifyToken` back at Parent

---

My components:

**App.jsx** (parent component):

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      spotifyToken: '' 
    };
    this.onConnectWithSpotify = this.onConnectWithSpotify.bind(this);
  };

// --> callback
onConnectWithSpotify(token){
      this.setState({ spotifyToken: token});
  }

render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Route exact path='/' render={() => (
           <SpotifyAuth
             onConnectWithSpotify={this.onConnectWithSpotify}
             spotifyToken={this.state.spotifyToken}// --> pass here
            />
        )} />
      </div>
    )
  }
```

**Spotify.jsx** (child component):

```
  handleRedirect(event) {
    const params = this.getHashParams();
    const access_token = params.access_token;

    console.log(access_token); // --> this prints valid token to console

    const state = generateRandomString(16);
    localStorage.setItem(Credentials.stateKey, state);

    let url = 'https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize';
    url += '?response_type=token';
    url += '&client_id=' + encodeURIComponent(Credentials.client_id);
    url += '&scope=' + encodeURIComponent(Credentials.scope);
    url += '&redirect_uri=' + encodeURIComponent(Credentials.redirect_uri);
    url += '&state=' + encodeURIComponent(state);

    this.props.onConnectWithSpotify(access_token); // --> callback here
    const {spotifyToken} = this.props
    console.log('Spotify Token', spotifyToken); // --> this prints token undefined

    window.location = url; 
    console.log(window.location )
};
```

Somehow I'm not managing to update `this.state.spotifyToken` at Child. I'm getting 'undefined' at console.

What am I missing?

Comment: You might need to pass the `spotifyToken` as props to the child component as well.

Comment: `console.log('Spotify Token', this.props.spotify_token); // --> this prints token undefined`. Your `Spotify component` does not contain props named `spotify_token`

Comment: You change parent's state by calling `onConnectWithSpotify`, React needs some time to re-render your component. So, it's not updated in your `handleRedirect` immediately, it's still the old `spotifyToken` value which is ''

Comment: makes total sense. so whats the solution?

Comment: add `componentDidUpdate` if you use class, or 'useEffect' if you use function to observe the changes.

Comment: care to answer?

Comment: I don't know if I answer your question comprehensively, I just want to provide some clues for you to debug and test your implementation.

Comment: does `access_token` really contained a value ?

Comment: yes, it does contain.

Comment: someone has suggested this question to be closed for being off-topic. this request makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setState method takes a callback function as a parameter in case you need to do something right after the state gets updated. 
setState(updater, [callback])

If you want to print the token when it gets updated then you could do something like this

```
onConnectWithSpotify(token){
   this.setState({ 
      spotifyToken: token
   }, () => {
      console.log('Spotify Token', this.state.spotifyToken)
   })
}
```

Also, the reason why it is printing undefined is because you are accessing the props wrong. you need to do

```
console.log('Spotify Token', this.props.spotifyToken);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using react context api. 
https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html
If you set your api token in the context object of the parent. Any child component can view the context data. Since you need to update the data from a child, the context object should also contain a function to update data by the parent.

1. Define context in different file named AppContext.js

```
import React from 'react'
const AppContext = React.createContext()
export default AppContext
```

2. You main parent will have state containing token and function to update the token. Parent will provide context

```
const Parent = () => {
    const [ token, setToken ] = useState(null)
    <AppContext.Provider value={token:token, setToken:setToken}>
       ......
    </...>
}
```

3. You child component will be the consumer of this context. Import context in child component.
4. Use 'useContext' api from react. You will get access to the token and function from your child component

```
import React, { useState, useContext, useEffect } from 'react'
const Child = () => {
   const { token, setToken } = useContext(AppContext);
   return (
     ....
   )
}
```